# JSF template: rendered page missing DOCTYPE

Tags: jsf, facelets

**TL;DR: I can't get the DOCTYPE header to appear on my JSF pages.**

I just inherited a JSF 1.2 project that's having some display issues under IE. I'm brand new to JSF, but I think the issues stem from the fact that the rendered pages (from "view source") do not contain a proper `DOCTYPE`.

The pages are composed of multiple parts, brought together using several layers of `<ui:composition>`. A typical page will look like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                template="../layout/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="body">
      <!-- html content goes here... -->
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Then the `../layout/template.xhtml` has:

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                template="./headertemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="menuSelection">
        <ui:insert name="menuSelection"/>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <ui:insert name="body"/>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="footer">
        <div class="footer">
            <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And finally, the `headertemplate.xhtml`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            contentType="text/html">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <body>
              <ui:insert name="body" />
            </body>
        </html>
</ui:composition>
```

I have left out many `xmlns` lines for brevity; I hope you get the idea.

**How can I get the DOCTYPE to show up in the rendered pages?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `<ui:composition>` from your **master** template, which is the `headertemplate.xhtml`. It doesn't belong there. The `<ui:composition>` will strip all other content outside the tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ui:insert name="body" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the doctype (and xml) declaration is *unnecessary* in template definition files (the ones using `<ui:composition>`). Just remove them.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)
- [Facelets 1.x docbook](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html)

Answer (score 1):

You must remember one thing, that everything outside ui:compostion tags is simply cut out, so the **DOCTYPE** declaration in your case is simply ignored.