# Set only non-empty attributes in JSF template tags

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets

I have defined a number of template tags in JSF 2.0, but have stumbled across a problem with conditionally setting attributes.

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition>
    <p:inputText converterMessage="#{converterMessage}">
        <ui:insert />
    </p:inputText>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

In the above case, when I set converterMessage, it works well. However, when I it out and call this component without attributes, then basically converterMessage is empty on the `p:inputText`, hence no message is shown when a converter error occurred.

Instead, I want the default message to be displayed in this case, so NOT setting converterMessage on the inputText.

Is there any way how to do this? I did try passing "null" but this, as expected, doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: Mmh don't think JSF templates are the way to go here for you... JSF Templates are designed for more general purposes like defining a page layout. What's the aim of `ui:insert` in your case? What are you going to insert there? Also keep in mind that defining `!DOCTYPE` is [unecessary in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505272/1199132).

Comment: `ui:insert` is used here to be able to insert validators into my field. Btw, the above problem also arises with the id attribute, among others.

Comment: Still don't understand your problem very well. PF documentation says that the `converterMessage` attribute defaults to `null`, so there's no message by default. So not declaring the attribute is the same as `converterMessage="#{null}"`. Apart from that, `p:inputText` provides its own `converter` and `validator` attributes which can be used to specify what do you want to use, so `ui:insert` makes no sense here. Have a look at [JSF composite components](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) as they seem to address your issue better.